# Prove $\int_Rf(x)e^{f(x)}dx\leq36e-96$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

This is a task from my last week exam.

Let $f$ be a measurable function: $R\to R$, such that $\mu \{x:f(x)\geq t\}\leq(1-t^4)\: \delta_{[0,1]}(t)$
Prove:
$$\int_Rf(x)dx\leq\frac{4}{5}$$
$$\int_Rf(x)e^{f(x)}dx\leq36e-96$$

I wrote it from my memory, hope I didn't miss any crucial assumptions. 
First part I did this way: 
$$\mu \{x:f(x)\geq 1\}\leq0$$, so we can confine $|f(x)|$ by 1 on $R$, because $|f(x)|$ may be greater than 1 only on measure zero set, which does not matter when calculating the integral. Then 
$$\int_Rf(x)dx\leq1\int_0^11-t^4dt=\frac{4}{5}$$

However I only acquired 3 out of 5 points for this part. I do not know how to do the other part, any help appreciated.

Comment: I think you have to assume that $f \geq 0$. Otherwise integral of $f$ may not be defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that $\mu(f\geq t) \leq (1-t^{4}) I_{[0,1]}(t)$. I think $1-t^{4} I_{[0,1]}(t)$ is a mistype.

A general result proved using Fubini's Theorem says $\int h(f(t))dt=\int_0^{\infty} h'(t) \mu(f\geq t)dt$ if $h(0)=0$, $h$ is differentiable an the integrals exist. Apply this with $h(t)=t$ and $h(t)=te^{t}$. I leave it to you to get the estimates for your integrals from these formulas.

Comment: Thanks, I will use an opportunity to ask you one more thing, is this even stated correctly? I have doubts because obviousely $f$ must be from $R$ as otherwise the integral wouldnt be defined, but then if we put $t=-\infty$ shouldn't we acquire the measure $\infty$ as it is the measure of $R$? Anyway, the task was surely for this trick in your answer.

Comment: The I equality in the hypothesis is only for $t$ between $0$ and $1$, so I don't see any problem with the way the result is stated.